# Full text query parameter for full text query string is not valid with ssrs

Tags: full-text-search, ssrs-2008

I am using Full Text Search in a table-valued function. The function is created on SQL Server 2008.
The function works perfect in SQL, however on SSRS I get this error:

**Full text query parameter for full text query string is not valid with ssrs**

the parameter @Search is of varchar(64).

Any idea what may fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `@Search` parameter in my function to be `nvarchar(255)` and problem solved!